# Input data buffer for multiple downstream operators in parallel in Flink

Tags: memory-management, apache-flink

I want to know how Flink handles branching out the result of one operator to multiple downstream operators. If I have an operator A that is connected to 3 other operators B, C and D in parallel, does Flink keep only one copy of the result and send it out to all 3 operators? Assuming that's the case, is the result removed once it has been sent to all 3 operators or is there a garbage collection process?

I haven't found anything concrete about this topic in the Flink documentation. Any relevant resource regarding this topic is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before sending record A to operators B, C, D, FLINK serialise record A into bytes. Then those bytes will be copied into buffer pools for sub-partitions for different operators, so there will be multiple copies of record A.

Record A will be GC later.

Comment: So that would mean in scenarios where there are multiple parallel operators, an external data store like redis would be much more efficient in terms of memory. Can you please share the sources where you found this information from? I can't seem to find anything regarding this topic.

Comment: @sunny That's internal memory management of FLINK. To get more details, you can check the code from `OutputCollector`, `ResultPartitionWriter`. What's REDIS here for? If you compose a FLINK streaming job, the data exchange between different operators are manipulated by FLINK automatically. Unless in your job, there some big data blocks, you can try to save them into REDIS and only carry REDIS key info in FLINK streaming job, but pay attention to the overhead of REDIS access.

Comment: Well that's exactly the problem. The data is quite big and it needs to go through several different operators in parallel. That's why I was thinking of a solution with an external data store. Thanks for the information. I'll check them out.